# $\cos2\theta +\cos\theta +k = 0 $ - set of all values of $k$ for which there is a solution

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

The set of all values of $k$ (real), such that the equation $\cos2\theta +\cos\theta +k = 0 $ admits a solution for $\theta$ is?

**MY ATTEMPT:**
I substituted $\cos2\theta$ with $2\cos^2\theta - 1 $. On completing the square in the given I found out that the minimum value of k is -2. But that is wrong. It should be $0$. Right? 
So how should I solve? Also how do I find the maximum as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$2\cos^2\theta+\cos\theta+k-1=0\iff(4\cos\theta+1)^2=9-8k$$

As $-1\le\cos\theta\le1,$

$-3\le4\cos\theta+1\le5\implies0\le(4\cos\theta+1)^2\le25$

Answer (score 2):

> It should be 0.Right?

No, the minimum value of $k$ is not $0$.

One way is to represent $k$ by $\cos\theta$. We have
$$k=-2\cos^2\theta-\cos\theta+1=-2\left(\cos\theta+\frac 14\right)^2+\frac 98$$
Now, considering the parabola with $-1\le\cos\theta\le 1$ gives that $\color{red}{k_{\text{max}}=\frac 98}$ when $\cos\theta=-1/4$, and $\color{red}{k_{\min}=-2}$ when $\cos\theta=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos 2\theta +\cos \theta=-k$$
$$2\cos^ 2\theta+\cos \theta-1=-k$$
Let $\cos \theta=t$, $-1\le t \le1$ and $f(t)=2t^2+t-1$

If $-1\le t \le1$, then $$-\frac98\le f(t)\le2$$
[image]

Then $$-\frac98\le -k\le2$$
Hence $$-2\le k\le \frac98$$

Answer (score 1):

$2\cos^2\theta -1+\cos\theta+k=0$  let $\cos\theta=x$ then $-k=2x^2+x-1=p(x)$ (let)  
$-1\le\cos\theta\le1$  or $-1 \le x \le 1$

$p(-1)=0$ and $p(1)=2$ now differentiation of $p(x)=0$ give us the minima so $x=-1/4$ is minima 
$p(-1/4)=-9/8$ 
so $-9/8 \le p(x) \le 2$
so $-9/8 \le -k \le 2$
so $9/8 \ge k \ge -2$

Now your question it can be $-2$ put $\theta=0$